# Filling color in grid view based on sql query output

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, colors

I have a table which we will use daily basis(one time). am using a query to whether it has been entered today or not. if entry is there for today, i should mark as green. if not there, i shoiuld mark as red color. given below coding not working for me. Can anyone help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Handover where Facility='Facility'", con);
try
{
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Text = "Chennai";
      GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text = "Annanagar";
      GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].ControlStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
catch
{
      GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Text = "Chennai";
      GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text = "Annanagar";
      GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].ControlStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: How many column your GridView has? And why you use `ExecuteNonQuery` with a `SELECT` statement? I don't see any point to use it. It just executes your query and what..? It doesn't even get any value.

Comment: @user..where is the data binding logic for gridview ??

Comment: @User..I dont think one would use ExceuteNOnQuery() for a select statement

Comment: you are trying to access a cell that does not exist. be sure you have enough columns. My guess is  that Cells[2] does not exist.Also, consider using parameters instead of writing 'Facility'. And use var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: i have 3 column and i done want to bind the data from sql table to gridview. Just if the query has any values, then it will green color in a cell. If the query dosen't have any values, then it will be red color in a cell.

Comment: if the query has any values then will color green. if not will color red

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void GetGrid()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserDetails", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == "k" && GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text == "j")
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].ControlStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        else
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].ControlStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```